# Appending node to the end of a linked list in C; infinite loop problem

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, while-loop, doubly-linked-list

```
dlistint_t *add_dnodeint_end(dlistint_t **head, const int n)
{
     dlistint_t *head_ref, *new;

     new = malloc(sizeof(dlistint_t);
     if (!new)
          return (NULL);

     new->n = n;
     new->next = NULL;
     new->prev = NULL;

     if (!(*head))
     {
          *head = new;
          return (new);
     }

     head_ref = *head;
     while (head_ref)
     {
          if (!head_ref->next)
          {
               head_ref->next = new;
               new->prev = head_ref;
               /* I need clarity here */
               head_ref = head_ref->next;
          }
          head_ref = head_ref->next;
     }
     return (new);
}
```

The function adds a new node to the end of a doubly linked list but my problem is with the `if` block in `while` loop.
If i remove the line `head_ref = head_ref->next;` the `while` loop runs infinitely. When i use a `break;` statement, it doesn't work for all cases. My confusion now is that I expect the `head_ref = head_ref->next;` statement outside the `if` block to always execute even when the if-condition is met thus terminating the loop.

I thought to ask because i did not find an answer that explains this clearly. Please link me if you find any that explains this well.

Comment: `new->prev = head-ref;` That will not compile. Please provide your actual code as a complete [mre] as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: Clarity would be to remove the 'advance' inside the if block...

Comment: The list gets longer when you add something to it. When you remove this line, the loop keeps trying to add the new node to the end of itself.

Comment: @kaylum Sorry that was typing error, i meant to write  `new->prev = head_ref;`

Comment: @user253751 Wow,, thanks. I just realized that after adding a node to the end of the list, i have to update `head_ref` in the if block so the statement outside the if scope can terminate the loop.

Comment: After you add the node to the end inside the `if` you are done so you should return right then.  There is no more list (because you are at the end) so you must not continue traversing - if you do continue traversing you will move past the node you just inserted get to the new end and insert it again... over and over.

Comment: Even better @JerryJeremiah
I've been looking for an alternative to what i have. Thanks

Comment: Debug a failing example to find the cause of the unwanted behavior.

Comment: Your code cannot be tested, please read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post a complete and reproducible program.  You say where you think your problem is, and what I can be sure is that, if you knew where the problem was, you should have been able to correct it yourself in the first place.

Comment: @LuisColorado The code is automatically tested by a checker. The main function of the test case calls two functions i don't have access to but i have an idea of what they do by their names. The main function adds some nodes to the end of the doubly linked list, then calls the first function that prints the list from head to tail then the second that prints from tail back to head. This kind of test case showed that there's a difference when i use the `break` statement and when i used my hacky approach. The difference and best practice was all i wanted to know.

Comment: I have tested myself code from codility or such kinds of places, and normally no problem is expected to build it independently.  If you don't have access to those functions, you can make stubs or something to allow you to publish a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  If you don't make a smal effort to help us testing your code, we are unable to reproduce your problem in a non-polluted way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have the comment `/* I need clarity here */`, there should be a `return new;` (or you should break out of the loop) as without it you'll make `head_ref` NULL with `head_ref = head_ref->next` and then the next (same) statement will make an invalid reference.

If is more natural to remove that `if` block and put that logic *after* the loop, and have the loop condition such that it ends when you're at the tail node.

I would not call this variable `head_ref`, because it stops being that "head" once you start looping. Maybe call it `current`:

```
dlistint_t *add_dnodeint_end(dlistint_t **head, const int n)
{
     dlistint_t *current, *new;

     new = malloc(sizeof(dlistint_t)); // missing parenthesis
     if (!new)
          return NULL;

     new->n = n;
     new->next = NULL;
     new->prev = NULL;

     current = *head;
     if (current == NULL)
     {
          *head = new;
          return new;
     }

     while (current->next != NULL)  // Exit loop when at tail
     {
          current = current->next;
     }
     current->next = new;
     new->prev = current;
     return new;
}
```